# Parser expression grammar - how to match any string excluding a single character?

Tags: parsing, rust, grammar, peg, pest

I'd like to write a PEG that matches filesystem paths.   A path element is any character except `/` in posix linux.

There is an expression in PEG to match `any` character, but I cannot figure out how to match any character except one.

The peg parser I'm using is PEST for rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find the PEST syntax in https://docs.rs/pest/0.4.1/pest/macro.grammar.html#syntax, in particular there is a "negative lookahead"

> `!a` — matches if `a` doesn't match without making progress

So you could write

```
!["/"] ~ any
```

Example:

```
// cargo-deps: pest

#[macro_use] extern crate pest;
use pest::*;

fn main() {
    impl_rdp! {
        grammar! {
            path = @{ soi ~ (["/"] ~ component)+ ~ eoi }
            component = @{ (!["/"] ~ any)+ }
        }
    }

    println!("should be true: {}", Rdp::new(StringInput::new("/bcc/cc/v")).path());
    println!("should be false: {}", Rdp::new(StringInput::new("/bcc/cc//v")).path());
}
```